# Como fazer um ScheduledExecutorService lançar uma nova tarefa enquanto a anterior ainda não terminou?

Tags: java, multithreading

Eu estou implementando um scheduler para rodar algumas threads no meu sistema em intervalos x de tempo. O grande problema é que se a thread 1 ainda não terminou de rodar, a 2 não começa, mesmo o seu tempo tendo chegado.

No exemplo abaixo eu "forcei" esse erro, pois estava desconfiado que isso poderia estar acontecendo.

***Thread***

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MinhaThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: " +  sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 1000000000) {
            int a = 1;
        }

        System.out.println("CHEGOU AO FIM");
    }

}
```

***Executor***

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class ExecutorThreads implements ServletContextListener {

     private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;


     @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MinhaThread(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }



}
```

***Estou rodando a aplicação em um simples TomCat, não uso TomcatEE.***

**Resultado Desejado:**

> Ao iniciar o programa, a primeira thread será criada. 10 segundos depois, apesar da primeira thread ainda estar no loop, a segunda thread também é criada e começa a rodar.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger na realidade, eu quero uma nova instancia da classe "MinhaThread ". Ou seja, vão ter 2 "MinhaThread " rodando ao mesmo tempo. Talvez eu esteja errando ai?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger entendi!! Você poderia me dar um exemplo breve dessa solução como resposta? Em paralelo vou dar uma procurada aqui e ver se consigo resolver também.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Vou tentar, obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Implementei sua solução funcionou, minha única preocupação é: O fato de criar uma thread para chamar outra thread pode me causar algum problema? Ou a "outra thread" tendo como única função chamar o "minha thread" irá fazer a chamada e "morrer", portanto não existe problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível e isso é salientado na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.
>
> Se a execução da tarefa demorar mais do que o seu período, as execuções subsequentes poderão começar mais tarde, mas não serão executadas simultaneamente.

Uma possível abordagem<sup>(1)</sup> é o *scheduler* usar um outro Executor para executar a tarefa "demorada/longa".

```
@WebListener
public class Executor implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);

        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executorService.submit(new MinhaThread());
            }
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }    

}
```

Quando o *scheduler* dispara, a tarefa `MinhaThread` é executada recorrendo a um Executor do "tipo" CachedThreadPool.

[newCachedThreadPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) cria um Executor que usa uma *thread pool*. Novas *threads* são criadas se necessário ou as anteriormente criadas são utilizadas se disponíveis.

Nota: O nome da classe `MinhaThread` deveria ser `MinhaTarefa` ou `MyTask`.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup>Mais ou menos o sugerido pelo CarlosHeuberger no [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312332/como-fazer-com-que-o-executors-crie-uma-nova-thread-enquanto-a-ultima-ainda-n%c3%a3/312508#comment634346_312332).</sub>

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta!! Vou testar e dou um feedback

Comment: Alterei para sua solução, funcionou de acordo!

Answer (score 0):

A solução proposta pelo @Carlos Heuberger realmente funcionou:

***Main thread***

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MinhaThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: " +  sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 1000000000) {
            int a = 1;
        }

        System.out.println("CHEGOU AO FIM");
    }

}
```

***Thread Secundária***

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class OutraThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA");
        new Thread(new MinhaThread()).start();

    }

}
```

***Executor***

```
package backgroundProcesses;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;



@WebListener
public class Executor implements ServletContextListener {

     private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;


     @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new OutraThread(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //roda a qualidade a cada 5 minutos.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }



}
```

***Console:***

```
ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA
FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: 11:54:33
ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA
FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: 11:54:43
ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA
FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: 11:54:53
ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA
FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: 11:55:03
ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA
FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: 11:55:13
ENTROU NA THREAD SECUNDARIA
FOI, COMEÇOOU A THREAD: 11:55:23
```

**Eu vou deixar a pergunta aberta para ver se alguma outra solução venha à aparecer, mas por hora irei implementar essa aqui.**

Comment: Essa implementação parece-me errada. Pode aparentemente funcionar porque o teste não decorre com o tempo necessário para o evidenciar(causado pela razão da sua pergunta). Note que a cada 10 segundos a `OutraThread` está a definir um `scheduleAtFixedRate` que executa `MinhaThread` a cada segundo.

Comment: @ramaral Editei a classe "OutraThread", é assim que estou fazendo no momento, o que acha?

Comment: Julgo que funcionará. No entanto é preferível usar `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, já que ele reaproveita Threads criadas quando disponíveis.

Comment: @ramaral legal! vou alterar meu código!